# Mongoengine Log events specific to a document in a collection to another collection with new fields

Tags: python-2.7, mongoengine

In my project I'm using Mongodb with  mongoengine ORM(Python),

> MongoDB shell version: 3.0.3
>
> pymongo==3.1.1
>
> mongoengine==0.10.1

I Wanted to track events happening to a collection to a log_collection, with original documents fields plus some new fields.

That is when a document in the  Original collection is getting updated with an event, there would be a new document added to the log_collection.

```
class Original(DynamicDocument):
    identifier = StringField(required=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    field1 = StringField()

class LogEvents(DynamicDocument):
    pass
```

For this I tried to make use [mongoengeine switch_collection](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.switch_collection)

```
col = Original.objects.get(id=some_id)
col.switch_collection('log_events', False)
col.new_field = "new_field"
col.save()
```

When we call the `col.save()` ,

> 1) it update to the *log_events* collection with the primary key field (_id) of the original document, so we cannot log the multiple events pertaining to the same document in the Original collection.
>
> 2) Even if we change the primary key field(_id), to a new value and save(),

```
col = Original.objects.get(id=some_id)
col.switch_collection('log_events', False)
col.id=<new-id>
col.new_field = "new_field"
col.save()
```

Then as it calls the save method of the **Original** collection, and there are unique indexes with multiple fields on the **Original** collection, its not possible to save to DB.

1. Is there any easy way to log events to the LogEvents collection without much hassle.
2. What is the use of `cascade` and `cascade_kwargs` options with the [save](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html#mongoengine.Document.save) method, how can we make use of it..?

Answer (score 0):

> 2. What is the use of cascade and cascade_kwargs options with the save method, how can we make use of it..?

[Mongoengine Docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html?highlight=cascade#mongoengine.Document.cascade_save):

> cascade_save(*args, **kwargs)
>
> ```
> Recursively saves any references / generic references on the document
> ```

Basically, this determines whether or not referenced documents are automatically saved when saving referencer document.

I don't think it is related to your issue.

Comment: Jerome Could you provide some more info about it..?

Answer (score 0):

A simple option for your kind of problem would be to overload the `save()` method of the `Original` class. Something like this:

```
class Original(DynamicDocument):
    identifier = StringField(required=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    field1 = StringField()

    def save(self, value):
        #save the document in its normal collections
        super(Original, self).save() 
        #switch collection and save a new event
        with switch_collection(Original, 'log_events') as Events:
            self.new_field = value
            #let's give it a new id
            self.identifier = 'something new'
            super(Events, self).save()
```

Now everytime you save an instance of Original, you can pass in a value to be saved separately in the log_events collection. With a bit of creative work you can pass more than one value or set more than one attribute.

Comment: still its throwing `NotUniqueError`, as the Original collection has Unique Index on it.